# check elements of a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of 1000 lists of booleans which is the result of a duplicated() check on the original lists of numbers.  I need to find which of these lists contains a TRUE result and I need to know the position of the list where it appears in the 1000.  i.e. I can then type

```
my.list[[456]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

And then use this to delete the elements from my list where a TRUE appears

Comment: Try `lapply(my.list, which)`.

Comment: From your bit of code, it seems that you do not have a list of lists containing booleans, but rather a list of boolean vectors. This is an important distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# An example
l <- list(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(FALSE, FALSE), c(FALSE))
# The indices you want
l2 <- lapply(l, which)
# The number of TRUEs for each element of l
l3 <- lengths(l2)
# The initial list, without the elements containing a TRUE
l4 <- l[l3 == 0]
```

Comment: @Gregor My mind went to `any` as well and imo it's the better route since it more accurately reflects the intent of the code.